# Can't retrieve data from the result of mongoose's find method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to get the data from result of mongoose's find method.

```
SinceIdLog.find({},['since_id','saved_date'],{sort:{'saved_date': -1}, limit:1}, function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs[0]);
    // some processes
});
```

the output of 'console.log' in this case is what I want like following.

```
{ since_id: '214320642386968576',
  saved_date: Sun, 17 Jun 2012 13:16:04 GMT,
  _id: 4fddd8941390b38712000143 }
```

But, when I write like below

```
SinceIdLog.find({},['since_id','saved_date'],{sort:{'saved_date': -1}, limit:1}, function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs[0].since_id);
    // some processes
});
```

the output is 'undifined'.

Do you know why?

I save the 'since_id' of Twitter API's parameter in MongoDB.

In this code, I want to get the since_id to retrieve the tweets newly updated in using OAuth.

Regards,

Comment: What does `console.log(docs[0]['since_id'])` print? `docs.length`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extraneous `]` after `since_id` in the `console.log` statement.

Comment: JohnnyHK
Thanks.
This is a mistake in posting the question.
I modified the question.

Comment: Something must be off elsewhere then as that's the right syntax now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have getter function for `since_id` field which doesn't return anything? Check the schema.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once and I think parsing the result helped.

Try the following

```
SinceIdLog.find({},['since_id','saved_date'],{sort:{'saved_date': -1}, limit:1}, function(err, docs) {
    docs = JSON.parse(docs);
    console.log(docs[0].since_id);
    // some processes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone,

I found the cause.

I haven't correctly defined the Schema like following

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
SinceIdLog = mongoose.model('SinceIdLog', new Schema());
```

this works when saving the data.

```
var XXX = new SinceIdLog(Object);
XXX.save(function(err) {});
```

But it doesn't seem work well in finding.

I modified it and now it's working correctly.

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
SinceIdLog = new Schema({
    since_id: String,
    saved_date: Date
}),
SinceIdSchema = mongoose.model('SinceIdLog', SinceIdLog);
```

Thanks!!